# Java - Unable to add text

Tags: java, class, text, system.out

I've been practicing a bit of Java lately. I've made a random keyboard in one class and another class called form.

I managed to add in the keyboard method from another class.

But when I tried to add in a text ( System.out.println("text"); ) it won't allow me, and if I did it in the outside wrapper it won't display.

**Keyboard class:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Keyboard {
   public static void main(String args[]){
      System.out.print("Enter your name... ");
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Your name is " + sc.nextLine());

   }
}
```

**FillInForm Class Problem 1:**

```
public class FillInForm {


    Keyboard j = new Keyboard();
    System.out.println("text"); <-------------- doesn't allow me. Why?


}
```

**FillInForm Class Problem 2:**

```
public class FillInForm {


    Keyboard j = new Keyboard();
{
        System.out.println("text");  <---------Also doesn't work. Why?
    }
}
```

*This is just for practice, the classes and methods don't have to make sense*. Made it randomly. I just want to know why I can't display text in the class called 'FillInForm'.

I know this question is trivial, but can someone help me out please? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the statement in a *method* rather than in the class block. As a declaration, the `Keyboard` declaration can exist in the class block but not the `println` statement:

```
public class FillInForm {

    Keyboard j = new Keyboard();

    public void myMethod() {
       System.out.println("text");
   }
}
```

For problem 2. the issue is the same as you are again attempting to place a non-declarative statement in a class block.

Given that the input functionality is the `static` main method of the `Keyboard` class, this functionality is best moved to a `main` method in `FillInForm`, unless you wish to use `KeyBoard` as a wrapper for the `Scanner` class. If the latter is the case, you could create an instance method to access functionality from `Scanner#nextLine`.

Comment: For added clarity - the `Keyboard j...` line could be outside the method if needed. It depends if other methods require access to the `j` variable.

Comment: I did as you said but a error message occurred "Error: Main method not found in class FillInForm, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)"

I've added a main method as suggested. But it doesn't allow me to call the keyboard function from the other class which allows me to type text. Is there anything I'm missing? It now only shows the text, but cannot utilise the other class method.

Answer (score 0):

The code must be part of a method, which is not the case in the last two pieces of code.

Answer (score 0):

The code must be part of a method. And you need to add a main method to one class:

```
public class FillInForm {

... other methods ...

  public static void main(String[] args) { // static means, this method does not belong to an instance of the class, it belongs to the class itself
    Keyboard j = new Keyboard();
    System.out.println("text"); 

};
}
```

The main method is the entry point of your application, it is automatically called when your application starts